# do..while loop in bubble sort for linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, bubble-sort

I'm trying to understand this code but i don't understand the `do..while` loop with that `while(swapped)`. What is the condition to stop the while loop?

```
/* Bubble sort the given linked list */
void bubbleSort(struct Node *start) 
{ 
    int swapped; 
    struct Node *ptr1; 
    struct Node *lptr = NULL; 

    /* Checking for empty list */
    if (start == NULL) 
        return; 

    do
    { 
        swapped = 0; 
        ptr1 = start; 

        while (ptr1->next != lptr) 
        { 
            if (ptr1->data > ptr1->next->data) 
            {  
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next); 
                swapped = 1; 
            } 
            ptr1 = ptr1->next; 
        } 
        lptr = ptr1; 
    } 
    while (swapped); 
}
```

Comment: Read about the bubble sort... The inner loop let a "bubble" going up, the final condition occurs when no bubble has gone up.

Comment: @Boninissimo The function is incorrect because the pointer to the head node is not passed by reference. That is it does not swap nodes. It swaps values stored in nodes. But such a function shall swap nodes themselves.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [how not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question. We need to understand the problem correctly so please add all the necessary details that clarify your issue and/or (when related to code) post a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: We also expect from you [to do at least a little research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) and/or (when related to code) [writing code to solve the issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) *on your own*. Stack Overflow is not a code request nor a tutorial service for explaining code in general. Questions with insufficient information to understand or reproduce the issue or do not show any effort to resolve the problem will get closed very soon.

Comment: Yes but my question is specifically about how that do..while works, and Moray answer to my question. So i don't understand your controversy.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow how can i fix it to swap nodes themselves?

Comment: @Boninissimo For starters you need to pass the pointer to the start node by reference that is through a pointer.

Comment: How? declaring "void bubbleSort(struct Node **start)" and call the function as "bubbleSort(&start)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop gets stopped when no element was swapped in an iteration. As you see at the beginning of the loop `swapped` is set to 0. When an element cann be swapped the program enters the conndition `if (ptr1->data > ptr1->next->data)` and in this condition `swapped` gets set to 1 (which is the C version of `true`). The loop continues as long as `swapped` is 1.

Comment: To put the last statement a bit more clearly, a new iteration of the loop is performed if `swapped` has a nonzero value *when it is evaluated in the `while` clause*.  It is a point of sometime confusion that `while` and `do` ... `while` loops do not terminate immediately when the loop condition becomes falsey during execution of the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Based on that code you want to sort in ascending order a linked list.

You go through the list from the beginning and if the current node's value is greater than next node's value you swap them.

You do this until there are swaps to perform, that's what `while (swapped)` means.